# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException on 2nd run, same JAR

Tags: java, class, exception

I have a very strange situation, when running the same *JAR* file **SECOND** and **SUBSEQUENT** times it throws *NoClassDefFoundError* and *ClassNotFoundException*. On first run there is no problem. No changes between the runs except in DB. This happens on dev environment as well as locally. I would think that if there is a code problem it wouldn't run at all. Would really appreciate if anyone encountered such issue to share what it was.

[image]

Comment: Why are you censoring parts of the error? That doesn't help us at all, we need to see the entire error

Comment: Would have been faster to just copy/paste the text "ClassNotFoundException" since that is all that exists in the screenshot now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that upon running

```
spark-submit
```

with

```
--packages
```

there were some *jars* missing. So here we go))